# Emacs auctex inserts line breaks after inline math in an ugly way

Tags: emacs, latex, emacs24, auctex

I got problems with emacs/auctex fill paragraph which insert linebreaks after each `$blabla$` block, resulting in a poorly readable code. For exemple, hitting `M-q` on the following long line:

```
a $1$ b $2$ c $3$ d $4$ e $5$ f $6$ g $7$ h $8$ i $9$ j $10$ k $11$ l $12$ m $13$ n $14$ o $15$
```

Gives:

```
a $1$
b $2$
c $3$
d $4$
e $5$
f $6$ g $7$ h $8$ i $9$ j $10$ k $11$ l $12$ m $13$ n $14$ o $15$
```

I would like to have something like:

```
a $1$ b $2$ c $3$ d $4$ e $5$ f $6$ g $7$ h $8$ i $9$ j $10$ k
 $11$ l $12$ m $13$ n $14$ o $15
```

Note: I have the impression that fill-paragraph didn't have this ugly behavior when I didn't use auctex but the built-in latex mode...

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be fixed by changing the AUCTeX user option `LaTeX-fill-break-at-separators` (see [AUCTeX Manual [Filling]](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Filling.html)).

Hit `M-x` and type `customize-group` in the minibuffer, then type `LaTeX`.

Now you should be able to see the option `LaTeX Fill Break At Separators` in the newly created buffer. Click on it (expanding it) and uncheck the box next to `Closing Inline Math Switches`. Don't forget to save.